# Uni Objects .NET Running Query and getting result set

Tags: c#, .net, uniobjects

I've been playing around with UniObjects .NET.

I would like to be able to run a SELECT query and get the data in to a form where I can run through the data.

The documentation I've been using is at http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/universe/resources/technical-manuals/universe-v11r1/uonet-v11r1.pdf

I'm currently running the query using

```
            // UniCommans is a new instance of the CreateUniCommand() method
            UniCommand cmd = us1.CreateUniCommand();

            string UVDatabaseName = "SLCUST";

            // Command is the query that will be sent to the server to be rum
            cmd.Command = "SELECT " + UVDatabaseName + " USING DICT " + UVDatabaseName + " WITH CUSREF PRICECODE";
```

But I don't know how to get the data in to one of the data types objects that they provide:

- UniDynArray
- UniFile
- UniSelectList

  ```
          // OpenSession is used to open a new session to the database
          us1 = UniObjects.OpenSession("92.0.0.1", "username", "password", "/path/TOFILE", "uvcs");

          // Create new instance a UniCommand
          UniCommand cmd = us1.CreateUniCommand();

          string UVDatabaseName = "SLCUST";

          // Command is the query that will be sent to the server to be run
          cmd.Command = "SELECT " + UVDatabaseName + " USING DICT " + UVDatabaseName + " WITH CUSREF PRICECODE";

          // Buffer size for receiving data can be get/set using CommandBlockSize
          // 0 is unlimited, the full data set will be received
          cmd.CommandBlockSize = 0;

          // Execute() executes the Command on the server
          cmd.Execute();

          // A status response is returned as a string in Response
          string response_str = cmd.Response;

          Console.WriteLine(response_str);

          // Check for the response of the UniCommand
          // UVS_COMPLETE = The command was completed, or unsuccessful
          if (cmd.CommandStatus == UniObjectsTokens.UVS_COMPLETE)
          {


              // How do I loop through the data set from my query?



          }
  ```

I've worked out that I can run through a WHOLE table by using the following code:

```
// Create a Uni file, required for you can use a database file
UniFile custfile = us1.CreateUniFile("SLCUST");

// Create a select list from the ID returned from cmd.Response;
UniSelectList selectList = us1.CreateUniSelectList(0);

selectList.Select(custfile);


bool lLastRecord = selectList.LastRecordRead;

while (!lLastRecord)
{
    string s = selectList.Next();
    Console.WriteLine("Record ID:" + s);
    lLastRecord = selectList.LastRecordRead;
}
```

When I run the command I get the following response string

> 4665 record(s) selected to SELECT list #0

It's just how access the list '0', I've tried but it's how to massage it in to the right class type:

```
UniSelectList selectList = us1.CreateUniSelectList(0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting close.  The "SELECT" command will generate a list of keys into select list 0 by default.  So you just need to assign a UniSelectList object to that.  You don't actually want to look at the command response except if you want to check if the command generated an error:

```
 // OpenSession is used to open a new session to the database
    us1 = UniObjects.OpenSession("92.0.0.1", "username", "password", "/path/TOFILE", "uvcs");

    // Create new instance a UniCommand
    UniCommand cmd = us1.CreateUniCommand();

    string UVDatabaseName = "SLCUST";

    // Command is the query that will be sent to the server to be run
    cmd.Command = "SELECT " + UVDatabaseName + " USING DICT " + UVDatabaseName + " WITH CUSREF PRICECODE";

    UniSelectList uSelect = uSession.selectList (0);
    // Execute() executes the Command on the server
    cmd.Execute();

    while (!lLastRecord)
    {
      string s = uSelect.Next();
      Console.WriteLine("Record ID:" + s);
      lLastRecord = selectList.LastRecordRead;
    }
```

Comment: Thank god there is somebody out there that knows how to use this!  May I ask for a revision on the code... say for instance if I want to get the data out for fields "AGENT" and "CUSNAME", how would I get from the Record ID, to getting the actual data showing from these fields?  I'll edit your code so that it makes more sense.  Thanks soo much!

Comment: Instantiate a UniFile object for the file; you've already done that in one of the code snippets.  Then use the "read" method of the UniFile object to get the data.  That'll yeild either a UniDynArray or UniString object, both of which (I think) support the "extract" method - UniDynArray does for sure.

Comment: You'll need to find out what the field numbers ("attributes" in UvSpeak) are for the fields your looking for.  In a session on the Uv server enter "LIST-DICT SLCUST".  The field numbers are in the 3rd column.  There might be a way, via UniObjects to access the fields via the dictionary names, but I've only rarely ever seen any programs on the server side that do so.  Virtually everybody uses the field numbers in the Uv BASIC programs, as nobody would trust that a dictionary item wouldn't be messed with.  So "value = recordvar.extract(fieldno)" and cast it to a string.